# window.location.href.indexOf not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently using `window.location.href.indexOf` in my current project. I've noticed that it doesn't seem to work properly. For example this code that I made.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //Show Sign Up drawer if user clicks on referral link
  //It will show the Sign Up drawer once the word "referral" is found in the URL
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("?referral") > -1) {
    console.log('Sign Up Drawer');
    $(".header-form-container.signup").addClass("show"),
  }
});
```

This code what it does is to add a class in an element if the word `referral` is found in the URL. The add class being inserted will then slide a sign up drawer. Here is what happened during testing.

In my first test, I tried inserting the word `referral` in the url. After typing in the word and pressing the `Enter` key, the javascript I'm trying to run did not trigger

[image]

But after refreshing the browser or inserting the word again it now works. It currently shows the sign up section.

[image]

How can I ensure that the code `window.location.href.indexOf` will work in the first try or without refreshing the browser again. The website is built on a angular framework

Comment: And how do you insert it without refreshing the page. Of course you need to refresh it.

Comment: Are you using a javascript framework or router that puts the `#/` in url?

Comment: Yes, it runs on a angular framework

Answer (score 2):

If you only change the URL **after** the `#` sign, the page won't reload, since you're only changing the anchor part of the URL.
Your code wrapped in `$(document).ready(function () { ...` will only run once, when the page loads.

What you want to do is to add a listener for the route change event and run your code in that handler, something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("?referral") > -1) {
    console.log('Sign Up Drawer');
    $(".header-form-container.signup").addClass("show"),
  }
});
```

Comment: So I just need to move it outside of the `$(document).ready(function () { ...`?

Comment: @clestcruz No, then it would only run once even before the page has loaded. What you need to do is to add a listener for a route change in Angular and run your code in the handler

Comment: Let me try it, I'm not very familiar with angular since the project was just turned over to me

Comment: @clestcruz I myself am a bit rusty with Angular since I haven't worked with it for a long time now so my suggested code might need some tweaks in order to work properly

Comment: Browsing the net for answers. Not sure if this will work http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/urls-routing-and-partials/listening-on-route-changes-to-implement-a-login-mechanism.html

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because **your script (e.g: main.js) is executed only one time** when the page load.

You might want to use `window.history`to manipulate the browser history. You can update the query string with `pushState()`

[History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Hope it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by my script is executed only one time?

Comment: It should work because it does it when the page loads, so no need to refresh, this answer is not explained properly

Comment: I mean your code only run once, when the page loads.